# "If I did find out" vs. " If I found out"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, conditional-constructions, auxiliary-verbs, emphasis

> 1. **If I found out** the truth, I would definitely tell you.
> 2. **If I did find out** the truth, I would definitely tell you.

What is the difference between these two conditional phrases?

Comment: The similarity between the sentences is that the tense of the first clause fails to match the tense of the second clause...

Comment: I don't understand AndyT's comment - they both look OK to me.

Answer (score 1):

(1) and (2) are conditional **sentences**, not conditional phrases. Conditional sentences are formed by a conditional clause (in this case, "If I found out the truth / If I did find out the truth") and a main clause (in this case, "I would definitely tell you").

Both sentences are slightly different in that the verb in conditional clause (2) is emphatic, so we can imagine some preceding context in which the possibility of "I" discovering the truth is considered to be remote, for example:

- I don't think I will ever find out the truth, but if I **did find out** the truth, I'd definitely tell you.